# I've a pandas dataframe, where one column contains text. I'd like to get a list of unique words appearing in each row of the entire column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

r1=['i just got the count', 'come on hold on man']

df=pd.DataFrame(r1,columns=['text'])
```

desired output:

```
r1 = [['i','just','got','the', 'count'],['come','on','hold', 'man']
```

In the second row 'on' is repeated twice and the desired output shows only unique words.

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['text'].str.split().apply(set)
```

Output:

```
0    {got, just, count, the, i}
1         {on, man, come, hold}
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass r1 to a list comprehension using split.

```
r1 = [x.split() for x in r1]
```

[image]